# Abstracting socket io server from event name

Tags: node.js, express, websocket, socket.io

I am trying to create a SocketIO server that can listen to a variable event name (that a client will initiate) like

```
socket.on( X, function(msg){ // X = any event name provided by the client
    io.emit(X, msg); // Emit events to all the clients listening to the same event name
});
```

For example, if the client emits an event like `"eventX"`, server should be able to listen to `"eventX"` and emit to all other clients that are connected to the server listening to "eventX".

My idea here is that, Server should not care about the name of the event that a group of clients use and the same piece of server code should be able to emit events when a different name is used by the group of clients for communication.

Comment: You can very easily do this by creating one master message name that the server listens for and then have the first argument when it is sent by a client be a sub-message name of the client's choosing.  Other arguments could be sent that are specific to the sub-message name.  That could meet your requirements.

Comment: @jfriend00 That sounds like an excellent solution! Will there be any pitfalls in this approach when the number of clients increase (Of course, I will scale out to different ports and vms when that happens)?

Comment: Scaling to a large number of clients shouldn't really be affected by this scheme as long as you are only sending info to the specific clients that need it.  If you're over-broadcasting (e.g. sending messages to lots of clients that don't need them), then things could get inefficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can very easily do this by creating one master message name that the server listens for and then have the first argument when it is sent by a client be a sub-message name of the client's choosing. Other arguments could be sent that are specific to the sub-message name. That could meet your requirements.